# How to use the number of rows of a document to set a 'for i in seq' or equivalent in shell

Tags: shell

I have a script that uses a for loop combined with awk to read lines in a file, each line contains a couple of bits of information that is used in the rest of the script.

I am wanting to make the for loops length contingent on the number of rows in that file as this value can change depending on what is required of the function. So if the document had 10 rows it would read;

for i in $(seq 1 10)

but if it had 20 then;

for i in $(seq 1 20)

Is there anyway to do this?

edit:

Sorry I should have made my question clearer. Each line of file is read for variables, those are inputted into another program. I am in effect running the same program 20 times with 20 different variables. AWK is just a tool to read a specific line, I imagine I don't need to use it specifically.  it looks like this;

```
for i in $(seq 1 "$lines")


do

line=$i

read CHR CHROM start end RSID < <(awk 'NR == '$line PheWAS_SNPs.txt)
```

Comment: As pointed out in vgersh99's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62199106/207248), `awk` is line/record based. If you pass it a file name it will automatically perform actions on each line of the file.  What you have here is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), you're better suited at showing your script with for loop, giving sample input and your desired output.  The proper solution is likely not to have a for loop at all (if you're using [tag:awk])

Answer (score 1):

> I have a script that uses a for loop combined with awk to read lines
>   in a file, each line contains a couple of bits of information that is
>   used in the rest of the script.

In most/all cases you don't need a shell wrapper for `awk` to operate on a file - awk is quite capable to operate of a file by itself, e.g.:

```
awk '{printf("recordN:[%d] record:[%s]\n", FNR, $0)}' myFile
```

But if you insist:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

typeset -i n=0

while read myLine
do
  printf "recordN[%d] record:[%s]\n" "$((++n))" "${myLine}"
done < myFile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

lines=$(wc -l < file)

for i in $(seq 1 "$lines"); do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I wasn't encasing in quotation marks before having tried a very similar approach.